# Property FirebasePlugin does not exist on type 'window'

Tags: cordova, angular, typescript, firebase, ionic2

Im using the cordova-firebase-plugin in my ionic2 project
Im using it for firebase analytics.

In my typeScript file when i try to call the function

```
window.FirebasePlugin.logEvent("page_view", {page: "Event List"});
```

I get the error

```
Property FirebasePlugin does not exist on type 'Window'
```

I guess that i have to import it. Ive already added it to my project by running the command

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase@0.1.10 --save
```

And i cant find any reference to how to add this. Any help and I would be grateful

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you can not find a difintion file for it then you can just add the `FirebasePlugin` property to the window object:

```
interface Window {
    FirebasePlugin: any;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `declare var window;` after your imports and Typescript won't complain anymore about properties inside window.